# Choosing Ajax Calls by checking radio button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

This is my sample code. Here on click of a radio button, the if condition should be checked and the following ajax call should be fired. But its always fires the first ajax call

```
$(document).ready(function (){
$('#save').click(function (event)
{
    if ($("#im").is(":checked")) //check not working
    {
        $.get('../bus.php',
        {
            fxn: 'A',
            jsn: '{"name":"' + name + '"}'
        });
    }
    else if ($("#gm").is(":checked"))
    {
        $.get('../bus.php',
        {
            fxn: 'B',
            jsn: '{"name":"' + name + '"}'
        });
    }
    else
    {
        $.get('../bus.php',
        {
            fxn: 'C',
            jsn: '{"name":"' + name + '"}'
        });
    }
});});

<html>
<body>
    <input type=radio name="radio1" value="1" id="im"><label>A</label> 
    <input type=radio name="radio1" value="2" id="gm"><label>B</label>
    <input type=radio name="radio1" value="3" id="am"><label>c</label>
</body>
```

Comment: Works perfectly fine for me -> **http://jsfiddle.net/g2Bs9/**

Comment: may be your ID's are not unique...?

Comment: Checked the id's , they are unique. And yes the fiddle works. but every time it fires the same ajax call-the first one. Any idea why ?

Comment: Learn how to debug your programs. `console.log`, `debugger`.

Comment: Yes i did try my best to get the code running. i am not getting any errors. but the fxn called is always A

Comment: isn't the c-part request being fired?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code work perfectly for me too.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#save').click(function (event) {
    if ($("#im").is(":checked")) //check not working
    {
        $.get("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London",function( data ){

            console.log(data);
        });

    } else if ($("#gm").is(":checked")) {
        $.get("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=LosAngeles",function( data ){
           console.log(data);
        });
    } else {
        $.get("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=NewYork",function( data ){
            console.log(data);
        });
    }
});
```

});

http://jsfiddle.net/2P72N/

Are you sure that the problem isn't in the php code in the management of the "fxn" parameter?

Answer (score 1):

How about it?

```
var val = $("input[name='radio1']:checked").val();
switch (val) {
case : "1":
// code
break;
case : "2":
// code
break;
case : "3":
// code
break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
if ($('#im').prop('checked'))
{
  //Your Code
}
```

Comment: No Sir, Still the first function is called. The second one is not being called

Comment: If you are checking the first checkbox, then only the first if condition will be processed. the second condition will execute only if the fisrt condition failes. Try only if's not else's

Comment: Your fiddle file is working perfect when i changed to $('#im').prop('checked')

Answer (score 0):

Try filter `:checked` in your selectors as :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#save').click(function (event) {
        if ($("#im:checked").length) {
            console.log('IM');
        } else if ($("#gm:checked").length) {
            console.log('GM');
        } else {
            console.log('AM');
        }
    });
});
```

[updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g2Bs9/1/)